# vim todolist without clear screen

Tags: vim, nnoremap

I use `TODO` word in a comment as todolist item

```
" TODO this is a todolist item
```

and I show the items with

```
nn <silent><leader>tl :grep --exclude=*~ TODO % <CR> :copen <CR>
```

but with the first part of command (the grep section), vim clear the screen, this is very ugly.

how I can send the `grep` output to background and only display the `copen` window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `:vimgrep` instead of `:grep`.

`:grep` uses an external program, that's why it's "suspending" Vim. `:vimgrep` is an internal feature and, as such, doesn't "suspend" Vim.

`:vimgrep` can be slower than `:grep` when dealing with large numbers of files but it shouldn't be a problem in your case.

Did you consider `/TODO<CR>`?

Comment: I don't like `/TODO<cr>`, because with `copen` I can move over todolist items

Comment: ok, with you suggestion I change to `nn <silent><leader>tl :vimgrep TODO % <CR> :copen <CR>`

Comment: You don't need `<silent>`, you have too many `<CR>s` and this seems to be a perfect usecase for `|`. Try `nnoremap <leader>tl :vimgrep TODO % \| copen<CR>`.

Comment: I like more `<tab>` that `\|`

Comment: but, when I use `\|` or `<tab>` in some case I get `Press ENTER or type command to continue`, with <CR> I don't get this output

Comment: Why do you want to use `<tab>`? Do you mean `<bar>`? `\|` and `<bar>` are pretty much interchangeable and work well.